# I need to create a custom (mail merge) email in conjunction with MS Access's and MS Outlooks Data Collection feature

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, outlook-2007

I'm using the data collection features available through Microsoft Access 2007 and Microsoft Outlook 2007 to send out an email and collect data from the recipient.  The data is then stored in an Access Table.

The feature that I am using is explained here pretty well:  [Collecting Data Using Email](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/collect-data-by-using-e-mail-messages-HA010015427.aspx)

The issue that I have run into is that other than the email address, there's no way to customize the email that is being distributed.  What I'm hoping to accomplish is the ability to essentially do a mail merge of sorts to personalize the email.   This doesn't seem possible using the wizard approached described in the attached article.  Is this something that I could accomplish via Visual Basic or some other means within MS Office.

Comment: Other readers considering that data collection feature should be aware it has been removed from Access 2013.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178954.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've chosen the HTML-option you will get only text boxes and there is no way to customise the email if sent directly from Access. If you do not specify an email address, Access will generate the email so that you can type in the recipient - you can customise the email at that point.
If you do want all the fancy stuff (ie, customising the email, using drop downs, yes/no buttons, validation etc) then you'll need to use InfoPath as a source (again, if using Access). That's the application where you can build your form using validation and controls. The disadvantage is that the recipient needs to have InfoPath installed on their machine.

You could of course create an application to loop through your records and you can customise the HTML as much as you like then, this is probably best done outside of Office.